# Node mssql Error : "Connection is closed" cuando ejecuto varias consultas a la vez

Tags: sql-server, nodejs

Resulta que estoy usando Node y SQLServer y angular, cuando hago una consulta, no me sale error alguno, el detalle es cuando por ejemplo entro a un formulario y quiero que me carguen datos como tipos de cedula, tipos de usuario, ect. En el cual llamo una consulta por cada uno para cargarlos en sus respectivo select.
Según he leído, las consultas se truncan entre ellas, así que hice un delay para que diera tiempo en completarlas, sin embargo si entro a producción la cantidad de usuarios trabajando me saldrá esos errores y quiero solucionarlo de una vez por todas.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const  sql = require("mssql");
var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
var expressJwt=require('express-jwt');
var app = express();

var dbConfig = {
 "user": "sa",
 "password": "*****",
 "database": "****",
 "host": "localhost",
 "dialect": "mssql",
 "port": 1433
};

var  executeQuery = function(res, query){
 sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
  if (err) {
   console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
   res.send(err);
  }
  else {
   // create Request object
   var request = new sql.Request();
   // query to the database
   request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
    if (err) {
     console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
     res.send(err);
    }
    else {
     res.send(recordset);
    }
   });
  }
    });           
}

app.get("/api/station", function(req , res){
 var query = "select * from Estacion";
 executeQuery (res , query);
});

app.get("/api/educationlevel", function(req , res){
 var query = "select * from nivelEducativo";
 executeQuery (res , query);
});


app.get("/api/relationship", function(req , res){
 var query = "select * from parentesco";
 executeQuery (res , query);
});
```

Si ejecuto una a la vez me funciona, pero al cargarlas todas de una vez me sale el error "Connection is closed."

Agradezco toda su colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución.
Al parecer en el request se pierde la conexion al hacer varias solicitudes a la vez. Por lo cual en el constructor del Request debes colocar la conexión. Si no la colocas tratará de adivinar la conexión abierta, en ese momento puede que al hacer varias solicitudes escoge una conexión que está cerrada.

[link de solución](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/383)

Ahora queda el código así:

```js
var  executeQuery = function(res, query){
 var connection =  new  sql.Connection(dbConfig);
 connection.connect(function(err) {
    // ...
  if (err) {
   console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err);
   res.send(err);
  }
  else {
   // create Request object
   var request = new sql.Request(connection);
   // query to the database
   request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
    if (err) {
     console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
     res.send(err);
    }
    else {
     res.send(recordset);
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

Cambie esto:

```
sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
```

por

```
var connection =  new  sql.Connection(dbConfig);
connection.connect(function(err) {
```

Y en el request agregue la conexión:

Antes:

```
var request = new sql.Request();
```

Después:

```
var request = new sql.Request(connection);
```